# My element has a value until attach the method .toLowerCase to it

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my initial code that works flawlessly.

```js
const objNotes = [
  {},
  {
    title: "Be better",
    body: "Do better"
  },
  {
    title: "You are what you eat",
    body: "Eat well and responsibly"
  },
  {
    title: "Look good",
    body: "Work good"
  }
];

const findNote = (notes, noteTitle) => {
  const index = notes.findIndex((note, index) => {
    return note.title === noteTitle;
  });
  return notes[index];
};

const action = findNote(objNotes, "Look good");
console.log(action);
```

When I attach the method `.toLowerCase` like down below I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

and I don't understand why.

```
const findNote = (notes, noteTitle) => {
  const index = notes.findIndex((note, index) => {
    return note.title.toLowerCase() === noteTitle.toLowerCase();
  });
  return notes[index];
};
```

Comment: because there is an element in your `objNotes` array without a `title` property; namely, the first element which is an empty object

Comment: `{},` <-- where is the title? can't use `toLowerCase` on `undefined` as the error states. `notes.findIndex((note, index) => note.title && note.title === noteTitle)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first object does not have the property *title*, trying to `toLowerCase()` that is throwing the error.

You can check if the property in object exists or not before using `toLowerCase()`:

```js
const objNotes = [
  {},
  {
    title: "Be better",
    body: "Do better"
  },
  {
    title: "You are what you eat",
    body: "Eat well and responsibly"
  },
  {
    title: "Look good",
    body: "Work good"
  }
];

const findNote = (notes, noteTitle) => {
  const index = notes.findIndex((note, index) => {
    return note.title == undefined? '' : note.title.toLowerCase() === noteTitle.toLowerCase();
  });
  return notes[index];
};

const action = findNote(objNotes, "Look good");
console.log(action);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) when you want the item and not the index of the item.

To prevent the error when you call a string method on an `undefined` value, you can use [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) `note.title !== undefined && ...`. Assuming the `note.title` is always a string if not `undefined`, an `undefined` value would return `false` immediately, and if it's not `undefined` the rest of the expression (the comparison) would be evaluated:

```js
const objNotes = [{},{"title":"Be better","body":"Do better"},{"title":"You are what you eat","body":"Eat well and responsibly"},{"title":"Look good","body":"Work good"}];

const findNote = (notes, noteTitle) =>
  notes.find((note, index) => // use Array.find()
    note.title !== undefined && // the title is not undefined
    note.title.toLowerCase() === noteTitle.toLowerCase() // compare the strings
  );

const action = findNote(objNotes, "Look good");
console.log(action);
```